# Clear views cache on specific node

Tags: 7, views, nodes, caching

I want to clear the cache of specific node's view. In my database in cache_views_data table I found the cid of my view and the format is like 
"views_name:display:hash" but I cannot find this hash where is reffering to.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can clear cache of specific view:

```
cache_clear_all('ctools_export:views_view:' . $NAME_OF_YOUR_VIEW, 'cache_views', TRUE);
cache_clear_all($NAME_OF_YOUR_VIEW, 'cache_views_data', TRUE);
```

Comment: No, I do not want to clear all the view's cache. I want to clear the view's cache but only for one node.

Comment: What do you mean "only for one node"? Is this a particular block (i.e. display in views), or you mean one node *within* a view? If it's the latter, you can't do that I think.